How to compare in Python to TypeError using assert?
I write tests using Assert.  How do I compare to TypeError ?
Function
def calc_of_the_cost_of_delivery(distance: int, size: str, fragility: bool, workload: str) -> int:
....
    if distance > 30:
        raise 'The distance may not be more than 30 km for a soft cargo'
    elif fragility:
        cost += 300
....
return max(min_delivery_cost, cost)

Tests
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert (calc_of_the_cost_of_delivery(20, 'small', True, 'medium')) == 720
    assert (calc_of_the_cost_of_delivery(20, 'big', False, 'other')) == 400
    assert (calc_of_the_cost_of_delivery(50, 'small', True, 'high')) == ***TypeError***


I'd use a unit test framework if I were you... https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises (the alternative is to write a try-except block to capture the exception and then check it)

Normally, == TypeError . You can compare types, they are normal variables. Are you sure are you asking about compare? Are you asking how to check if a function throws a specific exception? Capture the exception and check. Are you writing tests? Assert is for assertions, better invest in pytest.

What @MatBailie suggests is the way to go, but if you don't want to use a unit test framework, you can simply do: try: calc_of_the_cost_of_delivery(50, 'small', True, 'high') raise AssertError except TypeError: pass

I don't even understand why the third line should raise a TypeError, I think a ValueError would be more appropriate
